# can i make infinite loop for pageview builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

i need to scroll pageview builder from both site..

if item is last  again show first item..
or if item is first then in left side it will be show first item.
like round list.

here is my code

```
   _pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: currentPage, keepPage: true, viewportFraction: 0.5);

     PageView.builder(

              itemCount: data.Genre.length,
              onPageChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  currentPage = value;
                });

                print(builder.Genre[currentPage2].title);
              },
              controller: _pageController,

              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return  animateItemBuilder(index);
              }),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awesome package.
https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider
You can easily achieve what you want.

If you further want your left and right items to be more smaller then,
Open the carousel_slider.dart library file and modify in line 299. value = (1 - (value.abs() * 0.3)).clamp(0.0, 1.0); Increase 0.3 to 0.5 and check if it meets your requirement.

```
CarouselSlider(
   items: items,
   height: 200,
   aspectRatio: 1,
   viewportFraction: 0.8,
   initialPage: 0,
   enableInfiniteScroll: true,
   reverse: false,
   autoPlay: true,
   autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
   autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
   autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
   pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 10),
   enlargeCenterPage: true,
   onPageChanged: callbackFunction,
   scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
 )
```

Comment: i also use CarouselSlider brother :(

but in carousel sider i can't resize left and right image ?

that't why client not satisfied for this..

can you resize height left and right image more?

Comment: in pageview builder i can resize both side image .. :(

Comment: Yea, You can play with the aspect ratio and viewportFraction. Try putting viewPortfraction to 0.5 in carousel slider.

Comment: but you can't make this https://i.stack.imgur.com/UESPJ.png
this type

because in this package 
both side few short then current image all time .
and you can't change this ..

in pageview i can resize more small from current image

Comment: Open the carousel_slider.dart and modify in line 299.                                             
value = (1 - (value.abs() * 0.3)).clamp(0.0, 1.0); Increase 0.3 to 0.5 and check if it meets your requirement.

Comment: i already tried this..
but this is not effect in slider...


and can you suggest me how can i modify a package have you any link?

i change many thing but its look like same no effect if i change carousel_slider.dart and save it..

Comment: You will need to stop and re-run. Hot restart or reload won't work if you modify any library code. Sorry, I didn't mention that. Hope this helps.

Comment: love you brother <3

now this is ok..

thanks and thanks <3

Comment: Welcome, Accept the answer if it helped.